# redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. Name or service not known

Tags: python, docker, redis

I am unable to connect with redis cache in docker in development environment. I am able to connect with redis on my local machine.

Following is the error trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in 
    full_dispatch_requestrv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in 
    full_dispatch_requestrv = self.dispatch_request()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
    File "/app/main.py", line 36, in redisstatus
    status = r.ping()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1378, in ping
    return self.execute_command('PING')
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 898, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1192, in 
    get_connection
    connection.connect()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
    redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. Name or service not 
    known.
```

Could some one help me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you post the code ? issue might be with your redis url or port might not be open to connect. are you mapping the port from container to host ?

Comment: I have this in my docker-compose.yml file                                                               
 redis:
    image: redis:5.0.6-alpine
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    hostname: redis_cache
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - redis-net
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data

Comment: And I am connecting to Redis like below                                                               
redis_conn = redis.Redis(host="redis", port=6379) .. in my application redis is running in one container and application running in other. This is working fine in my local machine and docker. But in DEV server I am unable to connect